# Data table with x columns built from 2D array with index?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable

I have a number of tables like so:

```
Date  | DataLabel1
------------------
0/0/0 | 15
0/0/1 | 12
```

The tables will be build dynamically and I want to combine them to make something like a spreadsheet or database table, with the index being the date. Then I would populate the data with a function like

```
Sub Add(date,datalabel,value)
   'Find date row / add
   'Find column
   'Set Value
end sub
```

I have played with datatables in the past but found them to be cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to achieve! You can create data tables the way you want them to be. What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many programming ways to answer this, I am going to suggest a couple for you try:

- Generic List of Classes that have Date and DateLabel members
- HashTables
- Multi-Dimensional Arrays
- List

For what your describing a DataTable would not cumbersome, it would be reasonable and its the easiest out of all the suggested Data Types, eg:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Date");
dt.Columns.Add("DateLabel1");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = date;
dr[1] = value;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = date1;
dr[1] = value1;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```